# Upload multi-part image to asmx web service via android

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I'm using the following java code to upload a multi-part image to an ASMX web service:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ContentBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;


public class PostFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:9001/upload.asmx/SaveDocument");
    File file = new File("c:/TRASH/zaba_1.jpg");

    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
    mpEntity.addPart("userfile", cbFile);


    httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
    System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
    if (resEntity != null) {
      System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
    }
    if (resEntity != null) {
      resEntity.consumeContent();
    }

    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
  }
}
```

My problem is that I don't know what to do on the server side.
The following code, which I used for regular file uploads does not seem to work.

```
[WebMethod]
public bool SaveDocument( Byte[] docbinaryarray, string docname)
{
    string strdocPath;
    strdocPath = "C:\\DocumentDirectory\\" + docname;
    FileStream objfilestream =new FileStream(strdocPath,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    objfilestream.Write(docbinaryarray,0,docbinaryarray.Length);
    objfilestream.Close();

    return true;
}
```

I'm guessing I need to do something special in order to save the multi-part file, but I don't know what.
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that ASMX service supports multipart HTTP requests.

Comment: I will have to opt for a WCF service instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I endded up using streaming, which is not possible in ASXM.
I am using WCF instead.